# Does mpirun know if the requested number of cores is bigger or smaller than the available cores in a node?

Tags: mpi, cluster-computing, slurm

I am considering which process launcher, between `mpirun` and `srun`, is better at optimizing the resources. Let's say one compute node in a cluster has 16 cores in total and I have a job I want to run using 10 processes.

1. If I launch it using `mpirun -n10`, will it be able to detect that my request has less number of cores than what's available in each node and will automatically assign all 10 cores from a single node? Unlike `srun` that has `-N <number>` to specify the number of nodes, `mpirun` doesn't seem to have such a flag. I am thinking that running all processes in one node can reduce communication time.
2. In the example above let's further assume that each node has 2 CPUs and the cores are distributed equally, so 8 cores/CPU and the specification say that there is 48 GB memory per node (or 24 GB/CPU or 3 GB/core). And suppose that each spawned process in my job requires 2.5 GB, so all processes will use up 25 GB. When does one say that a program exceeds the memory limit, is it when the total required memory:

   - exceeds per node memory (hence my program is good, 25 GB < 48 GB), or
   - exceeds per CPU memory (hence my program is bad, 25 GB > 24 GB), or

   when the memory per process exceeds per core memory (hence my program is good, 2.5 GB < 3 GB)?

Answer (score 1):

`mpirun` has no information about the cluster resource. It will not request the resources ; you must first request an allocation, with typically `sbatch`, or `salloc` and then Slurm will setup the environment so that `mpirun` knows on which node(s) to start processes. So you must have a look at the `sbatch` and `salloc` options to create a request that matches your needs. By default, Slurm will try to 'pack' jobs on the minimum number of nodes.

`srun` can also work in an allocation created by `sbatch` or `salloc`, but it can also do the request by itself.

Comment: I didn't know that `mpirun` can also run on resources prepared by `slurm`, this whole time I always use `PBS` with `mpirun` (or `mpiexec`) and `sbatch` with `srun`.

Comment: See more information [here](https://slurm.schedmd.com/mpi_guide.html)